# Why is Image request been blocked by CORS on MDN if crossOrigin is anonymous?

Tags: image, cors

I tried to create an Image to load some gifs from tenor but some are blocked by CORS, not all of gifs. Can anyone explain ?

execute below script on `https://developer.mozilla.org/`

```js
function loadImage(crossOrigin) {
  const img = new Image()
  if(crossOrigin) img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.src="https://media.tenor.com/images/d5b11025a5f24a73c53adeae124aff72/tenor.gif"
}
loadImage(false)
loadImage(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Load an image in non-crossorigin then in crossorigin leads to cors cause it was cached with non-crossorigin.

I found this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898528/2449929